# Simple connection query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, database-connection, ssas

I have a really simple question that may seem stupid to ask but I'd rather ask it and know now before I ask my IT department to do something and find out it's not possible.

I going to be creating cubes in Analysis Services 2012 and the question is can I connect to sql tables that are stored in Sql Server 2008 R2?

Thanks, and sorry for the noobish questions but I just want to be sure before I put the work request in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You definitely can use SQL Server 2008 R2 as relational source.